# Django-restframework with pandas

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am using django-restframework,pandas,django-pandas to make an api and i am getting the following output[image]

This is the data of a single user and each label represents a column name but I want the output in the following format

[image]

can anyone help to get the data in the desired format

My code is

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_view(request,id):
    qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id)
    df = read_frame(qs)
    df['x-Mean'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean())
    df['1.96*std'] = 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['Outlier'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean()) > 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['bmi'] = df['Weight']/(df['Height']/100)**2
    a = df.fillna(0)
    return Response(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `a` is a `pandas.DataFrame` and it corresponds to table, so during serialization it tries to represent all data for each table column. `DataFrame` does not know that you have only one value for each column.
Values have to be extracted manually:

```
a = {column: values[0] for column, values in df.fillna(0).to_dict().items(orient='list')}
return Response(a)
```

For more details check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: Thanks @zymud I added to_dict() method after df.fillna() and it worked   a = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')